# Prove that $|x+y|^2-|x-y|^2+i|x+iy|^2-i|x-iy|^2=4x\overline{y}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to prove that the following equation holds for every complex number $x,y$:

$|x+y|^2-|x-y|^2+i|x+iy|^2-i|x-iy|^2=4x\overline{y}$,

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $\overline{y}$ is the complex conjugate of $y$.

It looks like the polarization identity:

$||x+y||^2-||x-y||^2+i||x+iy||^2-i||x-iy||^2=4(x,y)$,

where $(x,y)$ is a hermitian inner product and $||x||^2=(x,x)$, but I am not sure how to properly deduce the first equality from the second one. It is clear that the complex modulus is a norm, but what is the link between $4x\overline{y}$ and $4(x,y)$?

Any other approach is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly the polarization identity, $(x,y) = x\bar y$ is the standard Hermitian inner product on $\mathbb{C}$. Note that $x\bar x = |x|^2$ if $x \in \mathbb{C}$.

Alternatively, just expand everything on the left hand side (using $x\bar x = |x|^2$) and do lots of tedious algebra, essentially recreating the proof of polarization.

Comment: So $(x,y)=x\overline{y}$ is a definition here?

Comment: Yes. You can check that it satisfies all the requirements of a Hermitian inner product.